# Angular change background color of selected array from list in *ngFor

Tags: css, angular, ngfor

When I click on multiple lists one by one; I want them to have a blue background on the *ngFor list. When list is clicked again; I want the background removed and removed from the selectedList array. Thank you for all your help.

app.component.html

```
<div class="list">
    <span *ngFor="let list of lists; let i=index" (click)="onListSelect(list)">
          {{ list }}
    </span>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
selectedList = [] // selected list
onListSelect(list) {
   this.selectedList.push(tag);  
}
```

//I can click as many list I want and when I click them I want them in the onListSelect and have blue background and when clicked again; background removed.

Answer (score 0):

Restructure the `list` collection to an array of an `object`

```
// declare tags: any[]; in component.ts file
this.tags = this.lists.map((l, index) => ({index, tagName: l}))
```

You can use `ngClass` on each item to highlight the row.

```
<div class="list">
    <span [ngClass]="{'highlight': tag.selected}" 
      *ngFor="let tag of tags; let i=index" 
       (click)="onListSelect(tag )">
          {{ tag.tagName }}
    </span>
</div>
```

Also, you have to make changes in the `onListSelect` function.

```
onListSelect(tag) {
   tag.selected = !tag.selected;
   this.selectedList.push(tag);  
}
```